# Decision Trees: Pruning Difficulties, not returning the amount of nodes wanted

Tags: r, statistics, classification, data-mining, decision-tree

I've been working on pruning a decision tree (in R) and I had the data cross validated where put that the optimal amount of nodes was 4 nodes (due to my cross validation. I proceeded to try to prune the data to 4 nodes and I get returned a 5 node tree. I compared it to the decision tree of 5 nodes and they look exactly the same.

I'm a bit lost. Why isn't it producing a decision tree of 4 nodes when my cross validation says it is the optimal amount of nodes? Shedding some light on this would help me

Visit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsDyW.png
 for the plots side by side

Comment: 4/5 probably is a *limit*, but doesn't guarantee this is exact.

Comment: I don't understand, mind expanding?

Comment: The parmeter maybe is a *maximum*, not a *must*.